# How to prevent a program from being uninstalled by a user with root permissions?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, uninstall, root, productivity

In order to solve [my need to a website blocker software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144938/a-cold-turkey-alternative-for-ubuntu-to-prevent-self-temptation?noredirect=1#comment1900094_1144938) on Ubuntu to fight self-temptation, I've decided to take a compound approach:

- Install a website blocker app
- Put password on that app to access the setting or to uninstall

Is there a way to do so?
I have the root access and I'm the only user of the software. Can I prevent my self from uninstalling an app with a password?

Comment: Ultimately, doesn't it all depends on one's self-control?

Comment: The root user must be able to uninstall any application. That is an essential requirement of the root account. The problem you describe is not a technical issue.

Answer (score 3):

No. Root can not be restricted on a running system. You have to show at least that bit of self-control yourself.

Otherwise you have to create a new admin user, give its password to a friend and remove admin rights (`sudo` group membership) from your own user.

Wait, could you still bypass this and boot into a root shell in rescue mode? Yes. But if even that is not enough to stop your temptation for whatever, you should probably physically remove all computing devices from your reach.

Answer (score -1):

Put the app on a CD-ROM mounted on your system!